# __set magic method with sql select statements

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have write up a code like bellow

```
class helper{
public function __set($table,$type){
global $dbConfig;
$pardConfig=new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbConfig[0].';'.'dbname='.$dbConfig[1],$dbConfig[2],$dbConfig[3]);
$sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE menu_type=".$type);
$sql->execute();

$sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE id=".$type);
$sql->execute();

$result=$sql->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
var_dump($result);
}
           }      

$helper = new helper();
$helper->pard_menu = "main"; <<--- OUTPUT array(0) { } 
$helper->pard_menu = 99;
/\_________________________________________ OUTPUT  

array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "99" ["menu_title"]=> string(8) "leftmenu" ["menu_type"]=> string(4) "main" ["menu_description"]=> string(14) "left side menu" } }
```

As you can see there is a menu_type called **"main"** but i doesn't fetching result from the db but **id** is fetching result.**SAME DATABASE TABLE.**

Comment: Please reduce code examples to the minimum needed when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings need to be quoted in SQL statements.

But if you use query parameters, you don't have to worry about quotes:

```
$sql=$pardConfig->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE menu_type=?");
$sql->execute(array($type));
```

However, you can't use a parameter like this for a table in a FROM clause.  You'll have to be careful to use only valid table names.

Comment: However, you can't use a parameter like this for a table in a FROM clause. You'll have to be careful to use only valid table names. CAN YOU EXPLANE THIS MORE ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211812/in-ado-net-are-there-restrictions-where-sql-parameters-can-be-used-in-the-sql-q/13211867#13211867  That question is about using SQL with ADO.NET, but my answer applies when using SQL with *any* language.